# help with finding materials in D&D 5e

Tags: dnd-5e

I shall play a campaign with my dungeon master in Faerûn, and wanted to know how to get a specific material in this specific amount.

The two specific materials is Iron golem without a soul, Mundane Crystal, and Stygian Ice.
The specific amount is one iron golem, 14 pounds of Mundane Crystal. 8 pounds of Stygian Ice

The Crystal is to make weapons of specifically the new **double bladed scimitar**

the Iron golem without a soul, and Stygian Ice. is for **paying home brewed** spell that creates a golem

> #### familiar creation
>
> You gain the service of a familiar that will replace the Familiar from find familiar, by creating a golem out of chosen materials either can be wood, stone, steel, Materials from the Upper Planes, Exotic Materials of the Frostfell or any magical Element. Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the familiar has the statistics of an Iron Golem, though it is a celestial, fey, or fiend instead of any golem. After the golem is dismissed, it can be resummoned with the spell find familiar
>
> Your familiar acts independently of you, but it always obeys your commands. In combat, it rolls its own initiative and acts on its own turn. A familiar can attack if it feels like it, but it can take other actions as usual. When the familiar drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. It reappears after you cast find familiar spell again.
>
> While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically. Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind about your senses. As an action, you can temporarily dismiss your familiar. It disappears into a pocket dimension where it awaits your summons. Alternatively, you can banish it forever. As an action, while it is temporarily dismissed, you can cause it to reappear in any unoccupied space within 30 feet of you. Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the spell when you throw it. If the spell requires an attack roll, you use your attack modifier for the roll.
>
> The limits of the spell.
>
> Golems have all the advantages and disadvantages of the matter they are made of.
>
> You are limited to only can create one golem at the time.
>
> **material costs for this spell**: 10 lb of the chosen material, a alive Elemental Myrmidon of your choice, sacrifice the Familiar from find familiar, and Iron golem without a soul

Comment: How is this not something you should be discussing with your DM?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. It's possible for the site to evaluate homebrew material and sometimes even answer questions about homebrew material if the material's similar to published material, but the site can't answer questions about stuff that the DM's fabricated that's also without precedent. (The site's just as much—if not more!—in the dark as you are!) You may possibly have better luck with a question *about* this question, like *What does it say about the DM's campaign when a homebrew spell requires components like these?* Thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 4):

## You have to adventure for these things

To get things in a roleplaying game, you have your character go to a place where they are available.

To get a sword, go to a place that sells swords, or find one someone has left behind in a dungeon. To get a scroll, go where they are sold, steal one from a wizard, or find one in a dusty ruin.

To get **an iron golem without a soul**, you will need to have your character go where one exists in Faerûn. They aren’t available in shops, nor is there one with a publicly-known location, so you will have to:

1. Go on a quest to gain the knowledge of the existence and location of an iron golem without a soul.
2. Go on another quest to go to that place and do whatever you need to do to take possession of the iron golem without a soul.

Similarly for the **crystal**: you need to find it somewhere and collect it from that location, or find someone willing to sell it to you. I suggest asking around towns your character visits for anyone who knows of a mine with enormous quantities of crystal.

Similarly for the **Stygian ice**: you need to learn what that is in the first place and where it exists, go there, and acquire it. It’s probably on one of the lower planes, or in a realm of your DM’s own invention.

**The basic idea is that you need to pursue these items in the game itself through adventuring, with your DM, not pursue them on the internet.** That stuff only exists in the imagination of your DM who invented it for that homebrew spell, so you have to go on adventures to find it and acquire it.